# Passing parameter to windows command script

Tags: batch-file

I need to pass argument from wsf file to bat file to windows command script.
In wsf file I have:

```
Shell.Run("Something.bat ",&varparam,1,true)
```

In Something.bat:

```
sftp.exe testcommand.cmd %1
```

In testcommand.cmd:

```
open user@address
put %1
```

But .cmd file does not get access to the parameter value. How can I get this to work?

Answer (score 1):

In order to pass values into a batch you can use `call`
Try this:

```
CALL Something.bat %varparam%
```

And I think part of your problem is that you are trying to pass values into a command file that is already part of a separate string.

You could get this to work by haveing your Something.bat create your testcommand file.
Something.bat:

```
echo open user@address testcommand.bat
echo put %1 >> testcommand.bat

sftp.exe -b testcommand.bat
```

It's not perfect but I'm pretty sure the syntax of

```
sftp.exe testcommand.cmd %variable%
```

is your problem.